# Query about "Conway's Game of Life" algorithm

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conway game of life in javascript( best sol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249820/conway-game-of-life-in-javascript-best-sol)

I am writing a code for Conway's Game of Life. I am taking 2 arrays; one for old generation, and one for 2nd generation. When I am trying to implement the rules there is an error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '-1' of undefined
```

Please tell me, how should I change the code so that the neighbor cell with -1 value can be removed?

The rules are:

The universe of the Game of Life is an infinite two-dimensional orthogonal grid of square cells, each of which is in one of two possible states, alive or dead. Every cell interacts with its eight neighbours, which are the cells that are horizontally, vertically, or diagonally adjacent. At each step in time, the following transitions occur:

1. Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by under-population.
2. Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
3. Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overcrowding.
4. Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.

The initial pattern constitutes the seed of the system. The first generation is created by applying the above rules simultaneously to every cell in the seed—births and deaths occur simultaneously, and the discrete moment at which this happens is sometimes called a tick (in other words, each generation is a pure function of the preceding one). The rules continue to be applied repeatedly to create further generations.

Here is the code:

```
window.conway =
    {
    };
    window.conway.maingame =
    {
    };

    conway.maingame = function(width, height)
    {

        window.a = [];
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.map = new Array(width);
        for( i = 0; i < this.width; i++)
        {
            this.map[i] = new Array(height);
        }
        console.log(this.map, "map")
    }

    conway.maingame.prototype.randomize = function()
    {
        for( y = 0; y < this.height; y++)
        {
            console.log("enter for loop")
            for( x = 0; x < this.width; x++)
            {
                if(Math.random() > .5)
                {
                    i = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    i = false;
                }
                console.log("enter function")
                this.set(x, y, i);

            }
        }
    }

    conway.maingame.prototype.set = function(x, y, val)
    {
        x = x % this.width;
        y = y % this.height;
        this.map[x][y] = val;
        console.log(this.map, "map2");

    }


    conway.maingame.prototype.get = function(x, y)
    {
        x = x % this.width;
        y = y % this.height;
        return this.map[x][y];
    }

    conway.maingame.prototype.neighbors = function(x, y)
    {
        n = 0;
        if(this.get(x + 1, y + 1))
        {
            n++;
        }
        if(this.get(x + 1, y))
        {
            n++;
        }
        if(this.get(x + 1, y - 1))
        {
            n++;
        }
        if(this.get(x, y - 1))
        {
            n++;
        }
        if(this.get(x - 1, y - 1))
        {
            n++;
        }
        if(this.get(x - 1, y))
        {
            n++;
        }
        if(this.get(x - 1, y + 1))
        {
            n++;
        }
        if(this.get(x, y + 1))
        {
            n++;
        }
        return n;
    }

    conway.maingame.prototype.newgeneration = function()
    {

        var newMap = new Array(this.width);
        for( i = 0; i < this.width; i++)
        {
            newMap[i] = new Array(this.height);
        }

        for(var y = 0; y < this.height; y++)
        {
            for(var x = 0; x < this.width; x++)
            {
                console.log("enter all for")
                newMap[x][y] = this.get(x, y);

                if(this.neighbors(x, y) = undefined)
                {
                    for( k = 0; k < this.width+1; k++)
                    {
                        arr[k]=[];
                        for( f = 0; f < this.height+1; f++)
                        {
                                arr[j]=this.neigbors(x,y);
                                arr.pop();
                        }
                    }
                }
 //Error is in this part of the code    
                //Rule 1: any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies
                if(this.get(x, y) == true && this.neighbors(x, y) < 2)
                {
                    newMap[x][y] = false;
                }

                //Rule 2: Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation
                if(this.get(x, y) == true && this.neighbors(x, y) == 2 || this.neighbors(x, y) == 3)
                {
                    newMap[x][y] = true

                }

                //Rule 3: any live cell with more than three live neighbors dies
                if(this.get(x, y) == true && this.neighbors(x, y) > 3)
                {
                    newMap[x][y] = false;
                }

                //Rule 4: any dead cell with exactly three live neighbors becomes a live cell
                if(this.get(x, y) == false && this.neighbors(x, y) == 3)
                {
                    newMap[x][y] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        this.map = newMap;
    }
```

CHANGE BROUGHT

Even after this change to the code, my answer is not correct. Please tell me why?

```
conway.maingame.prototype.neighbors = function(x, y)
{
    count = 0;

    if(x > 0 && y > 0 && this.get(x + 1, y + 1))
    {
        console.log(this.get(x + 1, y + 1), "vallue neighbor");
        count++;
        console.log(count);
    }

    if(x > 0 && y > 0 && this.get(x + 1, y))
    {
        console.log(this.get(x + 1, y), "vallue neighbor");
        count++;
        console.log(count);

    }

    if(x > 0 && y > 0 && this.get(x + 1, y - 1))
    {
        console.log(this.get(x + 1, y - 1), "vallue neighbor");
        count++;
        console.log(count);
    }

    if(x > 0 && y >=0 && this.get(x, y - 1))
    {
        console.log(this.get(x + 1, y - 1), "vallue neighbor");
        count++;
        console.log(count);

    }

    if(x > 0 && y > 0 && this.get(x - 1, y - 1))
    {

        console.log(this.get(x + 1, y - 1), "vallue neighbor");
        count++;
        console.log(count);

    }

    if(x > 0 && y > 0 && this.get(x - 1, y))
    {
        console.log(this.get(x + 1, y - 1), "vallue neighbor");
        count++;
        console.log(count);
    }

    if(x > 0 && y > 0 && this.get(x - 1, y + 1))
    {
        console.log(this.get(x + 1, y - 1), "vallue neighbor");
        count++;
        console.log(count);
    }

    if(x > 0 && y > 0 &&this.get(x, y + 1))
    {
        console.log(this.get(x + 1, y - 1), "vallue neighbor");
        count++;
        console.log(count);
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: That's a fair amount of code to read through and spot small mistakes. Mind being more specific about where it is? Perhaps run through it in a js debugger?

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: i am new to this... i am soo srry... will  edit it. srry

Comment: I HAVE ADED COMENT ERROR IN IT

Comment: The error `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` screams using a single `=` when you should be using `==` or `===`.

Comment: actully after adding == thr is an error Cannot read property '-1' of undefined 
i want that cell of -1 to be removed

Comment: Please use your shift key. It is I not i. [I fixed it for you.]

Comment: (1) Please take the time to write legibly. We are very forgiving of people with English as a second language, but this is not a chat room. "srry" = "sorry" and "u" = "you". The "." key is used to separate sentences, a capital letter to start them. (2) Please post the exact error message and indicate the exact line of code (as per your console error message). Adding "-----ERROR-----" is not helpful as we cannot see if it is the line before or after. Add something like "// Error occurs here" to the end of the line of code. Your console trace should give you an exact line number to indicate this.

Comment: Ok.... i have edited the question again. i am new to this forum. i am trying to execute the code from a long time

Comment: This looks like homework. If it is, please add the "homework" tag to the question.

Comment: You are still not checking the edges correctly. You really have enough information to solve this yourself now. SO is not a service to write your code for you. Just look at your code carefully. Remember that at the edges of the grid the cells only have 5 neighbors and at the corners they only have 3 neighbors. You need to make sure always that when you are trying to reference a cell with `this.get(?, ?)` that you are withing the bounds of your playing grid.

Comment: ^ yes to what @njr said. I'd add that you could output the co-ordinates you are testing using `alert`, to ensure that you're not testing non-existent cells.

Answer (score 2):

Use `==` for comparison (or even `===`). Use `=` for assignment.

This line is wrong:

```
if(this.neighbors(x, y) = undefined)
```

Should be a comparison, not an assignemnt.

**EDIT: To fix the second error**

I am 99% sure that the line you have marked is NOT the line that is causing the problem. Please check your console error and verify the line number carefully.

I am pretty sure the problem is because you are trying to reference a cell that doesn't exist. Consider the cells around the edges - there are no neighbours on the outside. You need to modify your code to check that you are not moving outside the bounds of your array.

```
    ...

    if (y > 0 && this.get(x, y - 1)) {
        n++;
    }

    ... etc. ...
```

Bonus tip: Always put your opening brace on the same line.

Comment: hey i did this... still thr is an error... actuly i want that the undefined cell should not be considered... how cn i do that ?

Comment: actully after adding == thr is an error  Cannot read property '-1' of undefined

Comment: i want that cell of -1 to be removed

Comment: Fix up the code and run it through a linter as suggested by @RichardTowers. That will automatically throw up errors like this one.

Comment: i am running it through titanium studio.. it running fine ..... just that "this.neighbors" error is not letting me move forwrd......

Comment: Updated answer for second error. I am pretty sure that the information in your question is showing the wrong place for the error.

Comment: yes... you are correct.. the logic i used was that when that cell doesnt edit it should ignore that cell........ how can i do that ?

Comment: and i cant use if (y > 0 && this.get(x, y - 1)) {
        n++;
    } 
as in this case i wont be able to consider the corners of the cell

Comment: @njr, +1 for a good answer. But bear in mind that brace style is hotly debated; the [next-line approach](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) is alive and well. I use same-line at work, where it is encouraged, and use next-line at home, since I prefer it.

Comment: @halfer: you're right, the brace style is hotly debated. In other languages it is a purely stylistic choice (and in C# I use the next-line approach). Unfortunately in JavaScript it is more than a stylistic choice, as it will give syntactically different results when returning an object literal (which is something that is done quite often). That's why I always opt for the K&R style when writing JS. People who are aware of this special case can code accordingly. But for beginners I think it's always easier to stick with one consistent style and not worry about the obscure quirks of the language.

Comment: @njr - ah thanks, I'm not sure I was aware of the special case for object literals; interesting.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: See my answer on this question's [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249820/conway-game-of-life-in-javascript-best-sol/11252097#11252097).

It's worth running your code through an inspection tool like [jsHint](http://www.jshint.com/) :

```
Line 11: window.a = []; 

Missing "use strict" statement.


Line 19: console.log(this.map, "map") 

Missing semicolon.


Line 20: } 

Missing semicolon.


Line 24: for( y = 0; y < this.height; y++) 

Missing "use strict" statement.


Line 26: console.log("enter for loop") 

Missing semicolon.


Line 29: if(Math.random() > .5) 

A leading decimal point can be confused with a dot: '.5'.


Line 37: console.log("enter function") 

Missing semicolon.


Line 42: } 

Missing semicolon.


Line 46: x = x % this.width; 

Missing "use strict" statement.


Line 51: } 

Missing semicolon.


Line 56: x = x % this.width; 

Missing "use strict" statement.


Line 59: } 

Missing semicolon.


Line 63: n = 0; 

Missing "use strict" statement.


Line 97: } 

Missing semicolon.


Line 102: var newMap = new Array(this.width); 

Missing "use strict" statement.


Line 112: console.log("enter all for") 

Missing semicolon.


Line 115: if(this.neighbors(x, y) = undefined) 

Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.


Line 129: if(this.get(x, y) == true && this.neighbors(x, y) < 2) 

Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.


Line 135: if(this.get(x, y) == true && this.neighbors(x, y) == 2 || this.neighbors(x, y) == 3) 

Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.


Line 135: if(this.get(x, y) == true && this.neighbors(x, y) == 2 || this.neighbors(x, y) == 3) 

Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.


Line 135: if(this.get(x, y) == true && this.neighbors(x, y) == 2 || this.neighbors(x, y) == 3) 

Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.


Line 137: newMap[x][y] = true 

Missing semicolon.


Line 142: if(this.get(x, y) == true && this.neighbors(x, y) > 3) 

Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.


Line 148: if(this.get(x, y) == false && this.neighbors(x, y) == 3) 

Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.


Line 148: if(this.get(x, y) == false && this.neighbors(x, y) == 3) 

Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.


Line 156: } 

Missing semicolon.


Line 8: conway.maingame = function(width, height) 

'conway' is not defined.


Line 15: for( i = 0; i < this.width; i++) 

'i' is not defined.


Line 15: for( i = 0; i < this.width; i++) 

'i' is not defined.


Line 15: for( i = 0; i < this.width; i++) 

'i' is not defined.


Line 17: this.map[i] = new Array(height); 

'i' is not defined.


Line 19: console.log(this.map, "map") 

'console' is not defined.


Line 22: conway.maingame.prototype.randomize = function() 

'conway' is not defined.


Line 24: for( y = 0; y < this.height; y++) 

'y' is not defined.


Line 24: for( y = 0; y < this.height; y++) 

'y' is not defined.


Line 24: for( y = 0; y < this.height; y++) 

'y' is not defined.


Line 26: console.log("enter for loop") 

'console' is not defined.


Line 27: for( x = 0; x < this.width; x++) 

'x' is not defined.


Line 27: for( x = 0; x < this.width; x++) 

'x' is not defined.


Line 27: for( x = 0; x < this.width; x++) 

'x' is not defined.


Line 31: i = true; 

'i' is not defined.


Line 35: i = false; 

'i' is not defined.


Line 37: console.log("enter function") 

'console' is not defined.


Line 38: this.set(x, y, i); 

'x' is not defined.


Line 38: this.set(x, y, i); 

'y' is not defined.


Line 38: this.set(x, y, i); 

'i' is not defined.


Line 44: conway.maingame.prototype.set = function(x, y, val) 

'conway' is not defined.


Line 49: console.log(this.map, "map2"); 

'console' is not defined.


Line 54: conway.maingame.prototype.get = function(x, y) 

'conway' is not defined.


Line 61: conway.maingame.prototype.neighbors = function(x, y) 

'conway' is not defined.


Line 61: 

Too many errors. (38% scanned).
```

There's really too much wrong here to narrow it down to a specific issue...

Comment: hey ; can be avoided in javascript.... this is juat the skeleton of what am upto

Comment: Yes, the semicolon issue is debatable, but if you follow some best practices it makes finding bugs much easier. Note that JSHint _did_ find the error `Line 115: if(this.neighbors(x, y) = undefined) Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.`.

Comment: yes.. but i have edited that part already