# Conway game of life in javascript( best sol

Tags: javascript, web

i am writing a code for conway game of life...... i am taking 2> arrays one fr old generation. and one for 2 nd genration.

**rules are : The universe of the Game of Life is an infinite two-dimensional orthogonal grid of square cells, each of which is in one of two possible states, alive or dead. Every cell interacts with its eight neighbours, which are the cells that are horizontally, vertically, or diagonally adjacent. At each step in time, the following transitions occur: **1.Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by under-population.

2.Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.

3.Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overcrowding.

4.Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.**

The initial pattern constitutes the seed of the system. The first generation is created by applying the above rules simultaneously to every cell in the seed—births and deaths occur simultaneously, and the discrete moment at which this happens is sometimes called a tick (in other words, each generation is a pure function of the preceding one). The rules continue to be applied repeatedly to create further generations.**

here is the code

I am getting a soln but i guess its not giving me the correct solution becuase its not checking the neighbors of the corners. i have marked that part

```
**

    window.conway =
    {
    };
    window.conway.maingame =
    {
    };
    conway.maingame = function(width, height)
    {
        window.a = [];
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.map = new Array(width);
        for( i = 0; i < this.width; i++)
        {
            this.map[i] = new Array(height);
        }
        console.log(this.map, "map")
    }
    conway.maingame.prototype.randomize = function()
    {
        for( y = 0; y < this.height; y++)
        {
            //console.log("enter for loop")
            for( x = 0; x < this.width; x++)
            {
                if(Math.random() > .5)
                {
                    i =true;
                }
                else
                {
                    i = false;
                }
                //console.log("enter function")
                this.set(x, y, i);
            }
        }
    }
    conway.maingame.prototype.set = function(x, y, val)
    {
        x = x % this.width;
        y = y % this.height;
        this.map[x][y] = val;
        console.log(this.map, "map2");
    }
    conway.maingame.prototype.get = function(x, y)
    {
        x = x % this.width;
        y = y % this.height;
        return this.map[x][y];
    }
    *********************************************************************************
conway.maingame.prototype.neighbors = function(x, y)
    {
        count = 0;
        if(x > 0 && y > 0 && this.get(x + 1, y + 1))
        {
            console.log(this.get(x + 1, y + 1), "value neighbor");
            count++;
            console.log(count);
        }
        if(x > 0 && y > 0 && this.get(x + 1, y))
        {
            console.log(this.get(x + 1, y), "vallue neighbor");
            count++;
            console.log(count);
        }

        if(x > 0 && y > 0 && this.get(x + 1, y - 1))
        {
            console.log(this.get(x + 1, y - 1), "vallue neighbor");
            count++;
            console.log(count);
        }

        if(x > 0 && y >=0 && this.get(x, y - 1))
        {
            console.log(this.get(x + 1, y - 1), "vallue neighbor");
            count++;
            console.log(count);
        }

        if(x > 0 && y > 0 && this.get(x - 1, y - 1))
        {
            console.log(this.get(x + 1, y - 1), "vallue neighbor");
            count++;
            console.log(count);
        }

        if(x > 0 && y > 0 && this.get(x - 1, y))
        {
            console.log(this.get(x + 1, y - 1), "vallue neighbor");
            count++;
            console.log(count);
        }

        if(x > 0 && y > 0 && this.get(x - 1, y + 1))
        {
            console.log(this.get(x + 1, y - 1), "vallue neighbor");
            count++;
            console.log(count);
        }

        if(x > 0 && y > 0 &&this.get(x, y + 1))
        {
            console.log(this.get(x + 1, y - 1), "vallue neighbor");
            count++;
            console.log(count);
        }

        return count;
    }***
    conway.maingame.prototype.newgeneration = function()
    {
        var newMap = new Array(this.width);
        for( i = 0; i < this.width; i++)
        {
            newMap[i] = new Array(this.height);
        }
        for(var y = 0; y < this.height; y++)
        {
            for(var x = 0; x < this.width; x++)
            {
                console.log("enter all for");
                newMap[x][y] = this.get(x, y);
                console.log(newMap, "newarray");
                //Rule 1: any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies
                if(this.get(x, y) == true && this.neighbors(x, y) < 2)
                {
                    newMap[x][y] = false;
                    console.log("rule1");
                }
                //Rule 2: Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation
                if(this.get(x, y) == true && this.neighbors(x, y) == 2 || this.neighbors(x, y) == 3)
                {
                    newMap[x][y] = true
                    console.log("rule2");
                }
                //Rule 3: any live cell with more than three live neighbors dies
                if(this.get(x, y) == true && this.neighbors(x, y) > 3)
                {
                    newMap[x][y] = false;
                    console.log("rule3");
                }
                //Rule 4: any dead cell with exactly three live neighbors becomes a live cell
                if(this.get(x, y) == false && this.neighbors(x, y) == 3)
                {
                    newMap[x][y] = true;
                    console.log("rule4");
                }
            }
        }
        this.map = newMap;
    console.log(this.map,"new generation")
    }

**
```

Comment: Looks jolly similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244266/conway-game-of-life). Have you tried the eminently sensible sugestions there?

Comment: yes but i guess that is facing the same problem. the corner cells are nt being considered.

Comment: Here's [the code in jsHint](http://www.jshint.com/reports/609017). Work through that report and fix the errors, then update your question. There's no way someone is going to fix all your bugs for you.

Comment: the code is not incorrect .. i have run the enitre code..... the result is not coming as expected due to some logic error

Comment: have a look at a code please .. and kindly help me to fidn out how can i deal with the corners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I trawled through your code in JSHint and fixed all of the issues, wrote some glue to test it in the browser and here's the result: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RichardTowers/ujmba/).

It looks like it's working to me, so I think the problem must have been due to one of the dozens of warnings that JSHint flagged up.

Re: your assertion that the issue was due to the corners, that's what these lines are for:

```
  x = x % this.width;
  y = y % this.height;
```

In my test case I'm using a 10 x 10, so when it comes to check the neighbours of `(9,9)` it looks at `(10, 10)` and `(10 % 10, 10 % 10)` is `(0, 0)`, thus avoiding looking outside the array. I believe this is what's known as a toroidal array.

The lesson we learn from this? Keep on top of the small issues, and the big issues will take care of themselves.

Comment: It was not a waste of time, it is good to teach that loads of small errors are vastly more common than a single big one. Good on you.

Comment: I agree with @TheZ - keep it up `:-)`. Helping people can be addictive on SO... it is a very peculiar time-sink.

Comment: hey yes. actually i use titanium studio. and there were no errors showing at that time. i tried to implement this one again but i am not geting the correct answer i think. because evn after the apllying the rules it is giving me the same array which i got after applying the first rule

Comment: I'm not saying you have to change your IDE, you just need to run your code through a linter like JSHint as well. It will suggest things it thinks might be wrong. Fix these, and you'll find you have far fewer problems. You're welcome to take the code from jsfiddle.